# Regex check against referrer URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, indexof

```
var orig = document.referrer; // Incoming URL
var check = new RegExp("boxes", "gi"); // Literal string, global + case insensitive.

// console.log(check);

if (orig.indexOf(check) > -1) {
    console.log('you came from the box section');
} else {
    console.log('you DIDNT come the box section');
}
```

Hi Guys,

I have a 'boxes' category on a site, where all box items have 'boxes' in the URL. A particular item from another category needs to be able to check whether or not the user came from a 'boxes' item. (This is an interim solution as I only have skin-level access).

When logging 'check', I get '/boxes/gi', which should be working when checking within indexOf, as a valid regex string.

I am not too sure why I can not get this to properly check, as the result is only ever that the user didn't come from the 'boxes' section.

I have a lot to learn, so in advance, I greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use string variable instead of regex

```
var orig = document.referrer; // Incoming URL

// console.log(check);

if (orig.indexOf("boxes") > -1) {
    console.log('you came from the box section');
} else {
    console.log('you DIDNT come the box section');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` does not accept a regex as argument. You either use your regex with `search`, or use `indexOf` with a string.

```
orig.toLowerCase().indexOf("box") > -1

// or

orig.search(check) > -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match()` with the `regex` to perform your logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = "www.someurl.com/boxes/gi/abc";
var regex = /\/boxes\/gi/g;
var mtch =  url.match(regex);
if(mtch !== null){
  alert('url has the value');
}
else{
  alert('url does not have the value');
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the referrer URL into a link element and retrieve its pathname. You should also probably check the hostname to make sure it's from your own site:

```
var url = document.createElement('a');
url.href = document.referrer;

var comingFromBoxes = url.hostname === 'yoursite.com' && url.pathname.indexOf('/boxes') === 0;
```

**Note**: the referrer is **not** a reliable value by any means and should not be considered as such.